# How can we plot the Fourier transform of a sampling pattern?

Tags: fourier-analysis, fourier-transform, sampling, python, sampling-theory

In Cook, [Stochastic sampling in computer graphics](https://dl.acm.org/doi/pdf/10.1145/7529.8927), the author is showing distribution patterns like jittered samples

[image]

and the corresponding code to produce the output:

[image]

He's also showing the plot of the corresponding Fourier transform:

[image]

But what exactly does this last picture show? I guess we take the discretete Fourier transform of the data which is formed by the 512x512 pixel grid (and either a value in that grid is 0 (black) or 1 (white)). The discrete Fourier tranform of such a grid (i.e. a two-dimensional array) is another two-dimensional array. But what is the plot showing? And how can we plot it using Python?

Comment: https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.fft.fft2.html ?

Comment: The only question is about the "shift": is the plot showing frequencies using $[-k,k)$ or $[0,2k)$? It seems that with lacuna in the middle is due to the fact that the sample has no lower frequency parts, so that would suggest $[-k,k)$.

Comment: @WillieWong Thank you for your comment. What is $k$?

Comment: @WillieWong I already compute the dft using the fftw library. The question is what does the plot show? If $a_{ij}$ is the 512x512 pixel grid and $b_{ij}$ is the dft of it, does the plot show $|a_{ij}|^2$ in the $(i,j)$th pixel?

Comment: $k$ is the frequency. // For the second question: it is probably some function of $|b_{ij}|$ (the picture looks like it is only black/white). Probably a threshold is set and everything above the threshold is mapped to white and everything below to black.